# DejaVu Sans Mono stopped displaying some Unicode characters

Tags: unicode, fonts, monospace

Unicode degree sign character ଀ (u+0B00) stopped displaying correctly on Linux Mint 15 Olivia, probably along with some other characters I haven't confirmed. I'm only sure about this particular character. It displays either as a box (here on StackOverflow via Chrome) or a 4-piece rectangle glyph.

Tested using DejaVu Sans Mono font in gnome-terminal and Sublime Text 2, before and after the problem. I can confirm it worked earlier today, and between it working and refusing to work I don't think I've changed any font settings.

Comment: Well it turns out I messed up with a simple typo and the question is irrelevant now. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186366/227700) I found out I should flag it with `Too Localized: "Find My Typo."`, but accidentaly flagged it differently and now I can't reflag it. I guess that's all I can do, as I don't see a way to edit the question to be proper. The question just wouldn't exist if not that stupid typo. I understand the downvotes and accept them, I deserve it for not paying attention. Hope that question gets deleted to avoid confusion and I'll try to improve in the future. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+0B00 `଀` is not a defined Unicode character, so I don't know how it ever worked.

Degree Sign is U+00B0 `°`.

Comment: Oh hell, I need to get more sleep and google more. Thank you very much, good sir.